# Any ideas why I'm getting this error in sprite kit when adding sound?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if (gameOver == 0) {
        //Player End Jump.
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, -40))
        player.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("sounds/jump.caf", waitForCompletion: false))
    }
}
```

> > *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Resource sounds/jump.caf cannot be found in the main bundle'
> >     *** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sound file `sounds/jump.caf` could not be found by your app. Where and how did you add it to your Xcode project?

Comment: I've added the sounds to the main Xcode project like I have with images

Comment: Don't worry worked it out...its case senstive was not putting capital in word lol

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me tonight.  While adding new sounds, all of my pre-existing sounds became disconnected from their Target. This lead to the crash listed above. I had to select each and re-check the box for Target.

Also make sure the same box is checked when adding new sounds.

[image: check Target checkbox]

Answer (score -3):

I'm texting in a smartphone. Hope this helps.

`let jumpSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("jump.caf", waitForCompletion: true);
        self.runAction(jumpSound);`